# Jquery Validator does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I am pretty sure I am missing something very obvious but I am trying to validate my one of the textbox with required condition and I am using Jquery validator for that. My code looks like below:

```
 var validator = $("#ForgotPassword").validate({
                rules: {
                    EmailAddress: { required: true }
                },
                messages: {
                    EmailAddress: {
                        required: "Email address is required."
                    }
                }
            });
```

My DOm is like something below:

```
<form id = "ForgotPassword" class="ui-helper-hidden"  title="Forgot Password" action="" method="GET">
                <p>Please enter the email address you registered with. We’ll send you an email with a password reset link.</p>
                <div class="inputwrapper _100">
                    <label for="Email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" id="EmailAddress" name="Email" data-bind ="value : ForgotPasswordEmailAddress"/>
                    <span id="EmailAddress_Error" class="ui-helper-hidden errorMessage" ></span>
                </div>
            </form>
```

But when I put a watch on my validator object on the run time, I do not see any error. Is is because I am looking at the wrong place or my binding are not right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this please or paste rest of your validation code:

For validation plugin you need to have name - `EmailAddress` in this case:

Hope it help the cause `:)`

```
<form id = "ForgotPassword" class="ui-helper-hidden"  title="Forgot Password" action="" method="GET">
                <p>Please enter the email address you registered with. We’ll send you an email with a password reset link.</p>
                <div class="inputwrapper _100">
                    <label for="Email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" class="EmailAddress" data-bind ="value : ForgotPasswordEmailAddress"/>
                    <span id="EmailAddress_Error" class="ui-helper-hidden errorMessage" ></span>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Tried changing name to EmailAddress but my validator object looks same... Just making sure that if my validation fails than my errorList property would have some values rather than being empty correct?

Comment: Hiya @Californicated see here **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/qw87Q/ *specially for you* `:P` you can see what you are doing wrong by comparing this - also not this demo contains a check where you can enter multiple email in one texbox.

Comment: @Tats_innits: I just saw at your Fiddler code and your validator object exactly looks like mine except the extra function that you have but on order for mine to work, I have to add some code like `f (!$("#ForgotPassword").valid())
                return;` But yours works without any call to valid() function.. and displays the message.. I am missing where the magic lies...

Comment: lol @Californicated might be `script src` is missing i.e. for validation plugin? `:)` `<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.6/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Ok now I get it what is going on. Your button is submit and it is doing a POST while in my code button press is calling an AJAX GET and until and unless the Form is submitted..... Jquery validation does not work..... That is what the exact difference is.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the name in rules and messages. You should be using `Email` as the rule and message  not `EmailAddress` because thats the name attribute on the control

Comment: I changed name to EmailAddress rather than Email so not both ID and Name have the same values but my validator seems to look same....